# django action with intermediate page keyerror

Tags: python, django, action, admin

I'm newbie in django and I'm doing my first educational project. I would like make an action with an intermediate page, but I receive :
***KeyError at /admin/students/student/ 'action***' 
Scenario:

1. User selects from "Actions" listbox , action called :
   **u'Перемістити у групу'**
2. Presses Go

---

New page should appears with the list of students and listbox to  select a group.
please explain where is my error. My code is listed below:

```
class UpdateGroupForm(forms.Form):
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all().order_by('title'), required=False)


def update_group(modeladmin,request,queryset):
    if 'change_group' in request.POST:
        form=UpdateGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group=form.cleaned_data['group']
            updated_group=queryset.update(student_group=group)
            counter=queryset.count()
            modeladmin.message_user(request,u"У %s студентів було змненно групу на %s")%(counter,group)
            return

    if not form:
        form= UpdateGroupForm()
    return (request,'/students/change_group.html',{'students':queryset,'form':form,'title':u'Зміна групи'})
update_group.short_description=u'Перемістити у групу'

class StudenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    action_form = UpdateGroupForm
    actions = [update_group]
    list_display = ['last_name','first_name' ,'ticket','student_group']
    list_display_links = ['last_name','first_name']
    list_editable = ['student_group']
    ordering = ['last_name']
    list_filter = ['student_group']
    list_per_page = 10
    search_fields = ['last_name','first_name' ,'ticket','notes']
    def get_view_on_site_url(self, obj):
        return reverse ('students_edit',kwargs={'pk':obj.id})
```

Comment: Can you share more of the details on the error page - at what line is it raising a `KeyError`? It could be `form.cleaned_data['group']` which looks like it should be `form.cleaned_data['change_group']`, no?

Answer (score 0):

code of my page:

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block content %}

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <p>Групу буде змінено у таких студентів:</p>
    <ul>{{ students|unordered_list }}</ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_group" />
    <input type="submit" name="change_group" value="Зберігти" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is code of my models:

```
class Student (models.Model):
    """Student Model"""
    class Meta (object):
        verbose_name=u"Студент"
        verbose_name_plural=u"Студенти"


    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,verbose_name=u"Ім'я")
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,verbose_name=u"Прізвище")
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True,verbose_name=u"По-батькові")
    birthday=models.DateField(blank=False,verbose_name=u"Дата народження",null=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(blank=True,verbose_name=u"Фото",null=True)
    ticket=models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,verbose_name=u"Білет")
    student_group=models.ForeignKey('Group',verbose_name=u"Група",blank=False,null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    notes=models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name=u"Додаткові нотатки")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.first_name,self.last_name)



# post_delete signal deletes student photo
post_delete.connect(remove_photo,Student)

class Group (models.Model):
    """Group Model"""
    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name=u"Група"
        verbose_name_plural=u"Групи"

    title=models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=False,verbose_name=u"Назва")
    leader=models.OneToOneField('Student',verbose_name=u"Староста",blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    notes=models.TextField(blank=True,verbose_name=u"Додаткові нотатки")


    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.leader:
            return u"%s(%s %s)"%(self.title,self.leader.first_name,self.leader.last_name)
        else:
            return  u"%s"%(self.title)
```